# Filter search function in Tkinter python for lists

Tags: python, list, user-interface, tkinter

So this is what my GUI looks like:
[GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jvdC.jpg)
,and where i need help with is if i type a subject code it must show all the students with the that particular subject. Here is my code for the search function and add function:

```
def add_student():
Sname = Student_name.get()
Ssurnname = Student_surname.get()
Sdetail = Student_detail.get()
Snumber = Student_number.get()
i = Students(Sname,Ssurnname,Sdetail,Snumber)
Sinfo.append(i)

iName = Student_subject.get()
iCode = Student_code.get()
iMark1 = Student_Mark1.get()
iMark2 = Student_Mark2.get()
iMark3 = Student_Mark3.get()
iProject = Student_project.get()
j = Subjects(iName,iCode,iMark1,iMark2,iMark3,iProject)
SSubject.append(j)

kCourse = Degree_course.get()
kCode = Degree_code.get()
kYear = Degree_year.get()
v = Degrees(kCourse,kCode,kYear)
SDegree.append(v)

popup_add()
student_list.append(Sinfo)
student_list.append(SSubject)
student_list.append(SDegree)

def filter_data():
top3 = Toplevel()
top3.geometry('300x300')
top3.title("Search")
Searchlabel = Label(top3, text = "Please enter the Subject code: ")
Searchlabel.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky = (W,E))
searchValue = StringVar()
top3.searchBox = ttk.Entry(top3, textvariable=searchValue).grid(column=1, row=2, sticky = (W,E))

def searchdata(*args): 
    print("*")
    resultList.delete(0,END)
    searchkey = searchValue.get()
    for student in student_list:
        if searchkey == student[0]:
            resultList.insert(END,str(student))
        elif searchkey == student[1]:
            resultList.insert(END,str(student))



top3.button_1 = Button(top3, text = "Search", command = searchdata)
top3.button_1.grid(column=3, row=2, sticky = (W,E))
```

Comment: If you aren't willing to take the time to format the code properly in  your question, why should we take the time to answer it?

Comment: @BryanOakley I coded this and this is where i need help, what is your problem?

Comment: The Problem is that we cannot check wrong formatted code for errors / problems. Fix your indentation and we can try to reproduce and fix the error. As stated in https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve a verifiable example reproduces the problem. Your code does not run due to indentation errors.

Comment: Is `searchdata` supposed to be nested inside of `filter_data`? Is `filter_data` supposed to be inside of `add_student`? Are you intentionally appending different types of data to `student_list`, or is the intent that the list contain tuples or objects where each element represents one student? What does `popup_add()` do? Unfortunately, there's really just too much broken with the code _as posted_ for us to help even if we wanted to. Even by making educated guesses about those questions, I can't understand what the problem is.

Comment: @BryanOakley can i contact you directly?

Comment: @BryanOakley here is my email 216020088@student.uj.ac.za

Comment: @MohammedIsmail: no, I don't do private consultations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Observations

In the code you posted, it appears that `student_list` is a list with exactly three elements: a list of `Students` objects, a list of `Subjects` objects, and a list of `Degrees` objects. I make that observation based on these lines of code:

```
...
Sinfo.append(i)
...
SSubject.append(j)
...
SDegree.append(v)
...
student_list.append(Sinfo)
student_list.append(SSubject)
student_list.append(SDegree)
```

I have no way of knowing if that's your intent, or if that's the first bug. I also have no way of knowing if it will always have exactly three or more than three (but always a multiple of three).

Assuming that it's intentional that `student_list` will always have exactly three elements, this loop is incorrect:

```
for student in student_list:
    if searchkey == student[0]:
        resultList.insert(END,str(student))
```

The first time through the loop, `student` will itself be a list of `Students`. The second time through the loop, `student` will be a list of `Subjects`), and the third time through it will be a list of `Degrees`.

### Suggestions

Assuming that your data structures are intentional and that your ultimate goal is to be able to generate a list of students based on a given subject code, you will need to iterate over the list of *subjects*, not students.

Given the current code structure, you would need to do something like this (using a temporary variable `subjects` for clarity):

```
subjects = student_list[1]
for subject in subjects:
    ...
```

However, given that the students are in one list but the subjects are in another, you need to keep track of the index in the list of the subjects so that you can use the same index to reference the related student.

Note: This would be much easier if the subjects were an attribute of the student, so you might want to consider making the subjects and degrees attributes of a student.

We can keep track of the index within the list of subjects by using python's `enumerate` function:

```
for index, subject in enumerate(subjects):
    ...
```

Within the loop, you need to compare what the user entered with the subject code, and if you find it, you need to insert the corresponding student in the window.

Without knowing for certain, I'm going to assume that the `Subjects` class provides the subject code as the attribute `code`. I have no way of knowing if that's a correct assumption.

```
students = student_list[0]
subjects = student_list[1]

for index, subject in enumerate(subjects):
    if searchkey == subject.code:
        this_student = students[index]
        resultList.insert(END, str(thisstudent))
```

### Solving the problem through better data structures

The real solution to your problem might be to rethink some of your design choices. Instead of keeping student info, student subjects, and student grades in three separate lists, you might want to consider creating a `Student` class that has the info, subjects and lists as attributes. With that, all of the data for a student is in one place.

For example:

```
class Student(object):
    def __init__(self, info, subjects, grades):
        self.info = info
        self.subjects = subjects
        self.grades = grades
```

You would then create `student_list` like this:

```
student_list.append(Student(Sinfo, SSubject, SDegree))
```

With that you can loop over these students in a slightly more easy and understandable way:

```
for student in student_list:
    for subject in student.subjects:
        if subject.code == searchkey:
            resultList.insert(END, str(student.info))
```

You can make this even easier by creating a method that can do the test for you:

```
class Student(object):
    def has_subject(code):
        for subject in self.subjects:
            if subject.code == code:
                return True
        return False
```

Then, your loop becomes even clearer:

```
for student in student_list:
    if student.has_code(searchkey):
        resultList.insert(END, str(student.info))
```

### Final thoughts

My answer could be wrong, because your question lacks a considerable amount of information. This is why we ask for a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that actually runs. Without it, we have to make many guesses and assumptions about your code. If the assumptions are bad, I will have wasted half an hour addressing the wrong problem, and you will have wasted time reading an answer that isn't relevant.

Finally, it would be easier for you to get help if you were to write code that conforms to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) naming standards. Your code is difficult to read because of your unconventional use of uppercase characters. People tend to not want to provide answers to code that is difficult to read.